# Is there a way to show when does the table was updated/created?

Tags: hadoop, impala, hue

There are several Impala table that should be updated continuously. I suspect that updating script stop working due to some other reason. In Impala, are there any command that can be used to track the updating status of a Impala table, or list the latest time step that a table was updated.

Answer (score 2):

The describe formatted statement will give you the create time of the table, but there is nothing for a last update time. A better approach may be to add create and update timestamp fields in your table which you would populate when you add or modify records in your table.

```
describe formatted yourTableName
```